# Get VoiceOver for a UISlider to read like in the iOS Settings

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, accessibility, voiceover

On the following iOS screen the slider uses VoiceOver in a specific way

[image]

The 'SPEAKING RATE' UISlider reads information about the slider when clicked:

"Speaking rate 65% adjustable. Slide up or down to adjust the value"

I'd like my `UISlider` to read out similarly. Instead I get "Volume Control, 50%, Adjustable". What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let slider = UISlider()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        // Set up the slider
        slider.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 20)
        slider.minimumValue = 0
        slider.maximumValue = 100
        slider.accessibilityIncrement()
        slider.value = 50
        
        // Set accessibility properties for the slider
        slider.isAccessibilityElement = true
        slider.accessibilityLabel = "Volume Control"
        slider.accessibilityValue = "\(Int(slider.value))%"
        slider.accessibilityTraits = .adjustable
        
        // Add the slider to the view
        view.addSubview(slider)
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into accessibilityHint.

Comment: So I manually set accessibilityHint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry, you're doing nothing wrong in your code.

Take a look in the user settings ⟹ **Accessibility - VoiceOver - Verbosity - Speak Hints**...

[image]

... and you'll reach your goal to **get VoiceOver for a UISlider to read like in the iOS Settings**.

Unfortunately, there's **no notification** to be aware of this value.